# In Vim, paste over text between two parenthesis?

Tags: vim, shortcut

Something that I find myself doing often is yanking the text between two parenthesis and pasting that over another pair of parenthesis. For example:

```
foo(int a, int b, int c)
bar(int d, int e)
```

becomes

```
foo(int a, int b, int c)
bar(int a, int b, int c)
```

Is there a quick way in Vim to yank the text from foo and paste it over the text in bar?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way would be `yi)` inside foo's arguments and `"_di)P` within bar's arguments.

`yi)` yanks the text inside the parentheses

`"_di)P` uses the null register to delete the text inside the parentheses and pastes the text, `vi)p` also works and avoids the null register

The only thing changing is the function name though, so you could also just yank the line and use `cw` (change word) to change foo to bar.

Comment: @DirkHorsten I added brief explanations.

Answer (score 16):

Yank the content of the first pair of parentheses:

```
yib
```

Visually select the content of the second pair of parentheses and put:

```
vibp
```

Comment: There is a [Vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/) episode on this topic: [Pasting from Visual mode](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/pasting-from-visual-mode/)

Answer (score 4):

Cursor over the first paren of `foo`, then use `y%` to yank all the text until the matching paren.  (You can also use `v%y` if you prefer to visually see the text you're yanking.)

Then cursor over the first paren of `bar`, then use `v%p`.  It selects the text up until the matching paren then pastes over it.

Answer (score 1):

I use [vim-scripts/ReplaceWithRegister](https://github.com/vim-scripts/ReplaceWithRegister).

Copy as usual with
`yi(`

Paste with `gri(`

Answer (score 1):

Use this to go to last parenthesis `shift + 5`.

Press 5 twice for the first parentheses.